# How to extract data from Offchain storage in client-side?

Tags: offchain, offchain-storage

I'm trying to access data that I'm storing through the RPC off-chain endpoint.
[image]

Is there any way to get the instance of off-chain storage in *service.rs* through which we can extract that has been stored using the front-end?

Comment: Please provide your exact code when you are writing the data to the offchain storage, and an exact screenshot of how you are trying to read it it via the RPC. I can already tell you that you are using the `set` RPC here, not `get`, which is wrong.

Comment: @kianenigma the way I read the question is the inverse of what you have. I think Pawan is saying they are storing the data through this `localStorageSet` endpoint as displayed, and now not getting anything back when trying `OffchainStorage::get()` in code. Not sure if this changes your answer.

Answer (score 4):

On the client-side we can get the off-chain storage instance from shared backend instance *(which is of type Arc < FullBanckend >)*.
This instance can be find inside *new_full()*.

After getting the Bankend's shared instance, we can access our off-chain storage like this:

```
// The relevant ocw storage instance.
let ocw_storage = backend.offchain_storage();

// Prefix for accessing values for our application.
let prefix = &sp_offchain::STORAGE_PREFIX;

// Get our value
ocw_storage.get(prefix, key);
```